# View pager with expandable listview not working properly in collapsing toolbar

Tags: android, android-viewpager, expandablelistview, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I am implementing collapsing tool bar with tab layout, and i used expandable list view inside view pager. code works perfect but when i scroll upside it will not showing all the data in expandable list view but it only shows whatever loaded on first time [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HiGmv.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DSRDj.png)

here is my collapsing toolbar code

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawerlayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/root_coordinator"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/collapseImage"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="192dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/app_bar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#999"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/primaryColorDark"
                app:tabMode="scrollable"
                app:tabSelectedTextColor="@android:color/white"
                app:tabTextColor="#EEE" />


        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/view_pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />


    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment_navigation_drawer"
    android:name="asndeal.com.asndeal.NavigationDrawerFragment"
    android:layout_width="280dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />
```

and

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="asndeal.com.asndeal.CatName">

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

<ExpandableListView
    android:id="@+id/expandableListView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1):

hello chirag set viewpager app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
and put viewpager out of appbarlayout,Than it will work fine.

Comment: thank you, but now it stops collapsing and also not able to scroll in expandable list view

Comment: u can use expandable recycleview in place of expandable listview . I tested using exapndable recycleview and its working fine.

Comment: thank you.. but i don't know how to work with expandable recycler view thats why i switched to expandable list view, so if you can post your code for expandable recycler view then it will be very beneficial to me..

Comment: @testmail: Can you please provide Expandable Recycleview overview code sample? I search on net, but not succeed. Please help me on this.